# Is the Select() method required for a LINQ query in Method Syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

Looking at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) of examples in the Microsoft documentation for LINQ I noticed something odd between the two 'identical' examples they provide to demonstrate the differences between Method and Query syntax:

```
int[]numbers = {5, 10, 8, 3, 6, 12};

//Query syntax:
        IEnumerable<int> numQuery1 = 
            from num in numbers
            where num % 2 == 0
            orderby num
            select num;

//Method syntax:
        IEnumerable<int> numQuery2 = numbers.Where(num => num % 2 == 0).OrderBy(n => n);
```

While the Query syntax ends in "select num;" the Method syntax does not contain "Select()" as I was expecting it to. Is Select() required to use in a Method syntax LINQ query, or is it just being more explicit than in necessary? Is it just required when there is more than one column of data? I cannot find anything in the documentation that says it is optional.

Comment: No, it is not necessary unless you need to perform a projection-transformation.

Comment: Is creating numQuery2 not considered a projection-transformation? Or is a projection-transformation just used when the data type is not simple, such as the List<string> that they use in the Select documentation?

Comment: Because the fluent API, each method is, by very definition, returning a value, there's no need to have a `Select`

Comment: LINQ is just functions.  You can call whatever functions you want.

Comment: `.Select(value => value)` would be pretty pointless.

Comment: Thanks all, I appreciate the quick responses I got. The other question, while slightly different, did answer my question.